# jQuery parse imdb html

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
  <a href="/country/us?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>USA</a>
</div>

<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Language:</h4>
  <a href="/language/en?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>English</a>
</div>

<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Release Date:</h4> 9 January 2011 (USA)
  <span class="see-more inline">
    <a href="releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>See more</a>&nbsp;&raquo;
  </span>
</div>
```

I need get key-value. eg: '`Release Date:`','`9 January 2011 (USA)`'

i can get key:

```
$('.txt-block').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).children('h4').text());
});
```

howto get value in this loop?

upd: solution

```
$('.txt-block').each(function() {                                                                                                    
    var key=$(this).children('h4').text();                                                                                             
    $(this).children('h4').remove();                                                                                                   
    $(this).children('span').remove();                                                                                                 
    var value=$(this).text().trim();                                                                                                   
    console.log(key,value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `contains` selector:

```js
var container = $('h4:contains("Release Date")').parent(),
    seeMore = container.find('.see-more');

seeMore.detach();
console.log(container.text());

//if you need both as seperate values:
var splitValues = container.text().split(': ');
console.log(splitValues[0]);
console.log(splitValues[1]);

//using your each
$('.txt-block').each(function() {
  var block = $(this);
  if (block.find('h4:contains("Release Date")').length > 0) {
    block.find('.see-more').detach()
    console.log(block.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
  <a href="/country/us?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>USA</a>
</div>

<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Language:</h4>
  <a href="/language/en?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>English</a>
</div>

<div class="txt-block">
  <h4 class="inline">Release Date:</h4> 9 January 2011 (USA)
  <span class="see-more inline">
    <a href="releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop='url'>See more</a>&nbsp;&raquo;
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.txt-block').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children('h4').text());
    // value
    console.log($(this).first().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text()));
});
```

This gets the contents of the selected div, and filters the matched set, returning only elements with nodeType == 3, which are text nodes.

Comment: what should be the result? What are the values in your XML?

Answer (score 0):

A simple one, try this:

```
$('.txt-block').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children('h4').text());
    // strip all html
    console.log(this.textContent || this.innerText);
});
```

**Update**: to remove see more, use `$(".see-more", $(this)).remove();`

Comment: @askovpen Don't try the code just like that, try to run and device your idea. Use only the second piece of code for your answer. It strips all the html and prints both `h4` text and the plain text http://jsfiddle.net/6fqhduok/3/